# How to animate basiceditfield in blackberry?

Tags: animation, blackberry, java-me, blackberry-editfield

In my j2me blackberry application, I want to open editfield to enter text when user clicks on search icon. I have search icon added at the top right corner, when user clicks on it, I want to open basiceditfield with animating from right to left. I want Animation should be like default search on main screen in blackberry. How to do this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do almost anything with the Blackberry Ui, if you understand it and are prepared to put the time in.  But what you see when you press the magnifying glass is something that someone has spent a lot of time doing.  There is API for doing anything like that (at least not one I have found).  So if you are not experienced doing BlackBerry Ui, as I suspect is the case here, then I would suggest that replicating what the BB engineers have done with the animation from the search icon on the Home screen to the search screen, is too difficult to justify.

A lot of these sorts of things are, in my opinion, just gloss.  They do not make the application any easier to use, just make it look flash.  Personally, I would spend your time on making sure your application works well, rather than making it look flashy.

I do recommend using the screen transition animations as a way of moving from one screen to another. These are fairly easy to use and when used correctly, provide a good visual clue to your user regarding the flow through your application.  I also suggest you spend some time making sure your assets (icons etc.) look good, on all the various sizes of BB that you are developing for.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Now Thinking to open another screen when user clicks on search icon. Thanks for your time.